# How many question marks is a question allowed to have before it becomes too broad?

Tags: discussion

This question [Which is more efficient: Return a value vs. Pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994995/which-is-more-efficient-return-a-value-vs-pass-by-reference) is highly upvoted and not un-useful, but clearly has multiple question marks and multiple questions.  However trying to flag it as too broad has been declined.

What criteria must be met in order to be able to ask multiple questions in one question?

Comment: Why are you assuming that whether a question is too broad or not is determined by the number of question marks in it?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple "questions" in that question, but they are all part of the _same_ overall issue. _That_ is why, at least in my thoughts, it's not too broad. I'm sure an argument could be made the other way, but I at least don't see it as too broad. Now if the multiple "questions" were not all part of the same issue, and each would need a completely separate explanation, that would indeed be too broad.

Comment: Is there a better flag for it @resueman?  I was under the impression one question per question was what we were supposed to stick to.

Comment: One overall _issue/problem_ is the maximum. If a couple of smaller "questions" make up that issue, and explaining those "questions" would not greatly expand the answers to unreasonable lengths, the question is not too broad. For example, "Why does X do this? Is this behavior harmful for me to use, or can I utilize this without sacrificing the security of the Y call?"

Comment: Highly specific to this question, he's thinking ahead of what the answer might look like. That's not a problem, it is a quality.  Surely also the reason it got so many votes and why it hasn't been closed even though it has been asked many times before.

Comment: If there is more than one question in the question, it is too broad. If the other questions can be edited out to make it not too broad without deviating from the original intent of the question, then you should do that.